# Select nested property from MongoDB repository with Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I like the parsing of method names in the `MongoRepository` so I don't have to write queries. But I was wondering if there is a way to use this pattern to only select a certain (nested) field.

My Document looks like:

```
@Document(collection = "elements")
public class ElementEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String type;
    private MetaData metaData;
    private String json;

}

public class MetaData {

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private final List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

I can search ElementEntities by keyword with this:

```
List<ElementEntity> findByMetaDataKeywords(String keyword);
```

I now want to get a list of possible keywords, but I don't find any documentation on how or if it is even possible with the method name pattern. I was hoping something like this might work, but it doesn't:

```
List<String> getDistinctMetaDataKeywordsAsc();
```

Is there a way to achieve this with just an interface method, or do I need to write a (SQL?) query?

EDIT based on a comment in one of the answers:
Assuming I have two documents in my elements collection:

1. has the keywords: "disclaimer" and "legal"
2. has the keywords: "footnote" and "legal"

I want to have a method that returns me a List with the three distinct keywords in alphabetic order: "disclaimer", "footnote", "legal"

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
       List<ElementEntity> findByMetaData_Keywords(List<String> keywords);
```

Comment: That is not what I want, or rather this is working as written above. I want to get all possible keywords of all elements.

Comment: can you add your expected output in your question

Comment: I added some more explanation of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, I tried many different combination with find or get. Spring then throws messages like this: No property findDistinctMetaDataKeywords found for type ElementEntity!
If I add By somewhere in the method it expects a parameter: Invalid parameter index! You seem to have declare too little query method parameters!] with root cause

Comment: for that you have to use mongo template `mongoTemplate.getCollection(COLLECTION).distinct(keywords);`